# Drawing small square box

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex

[image: empty check box]

I am trying to draw / create a empty box

I found an old answer , but
the problem is ,
it is not aligning to text / line

Help please

Comment: Use `\raisebox`

Comment: it worked, thanks

Comment: Please always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document, which reproduce your problem. Its image is not useful, since it can't be copied and tested in our computers. MWE code you should copied from your editor an past here in question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is solved by comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an alternative using `hyperref`'s `\CheckBox` commands:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
Tick \faCheckSquare[regular] the correct answer.
\begin{enumerate}
\item question text
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item \CheckBox[name=1first]{first answer}
    \item \CheckBox[name=1second]{second answer}
    \item \CheckBox[name=1third]{third answer}
  \end{enumerate}
\item another question
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item \CheckBox[name=2first]{first answer}
    \item \CheckBox[name=2second]{second answer}
    \item \CheckBox[name=2third]{third answer}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

As you tagged you question with `tikz`, let me offer you a very simple `tikz` alternative.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage   {tikz}

\tikzset
{%
  pics/checkbox/.style={% usage: checkbox={0} not ticked / checkbox={1} ticked
    code={%
      \draw[line join=round,line width=0.15ex] (0,0) rectangle (1.5ex,1.5ex);
      \ifnum #1 = 1
        \draw[line cap=round,line join=round,line width=0.15ex] (0.5ex,0.8ex) -- (0.75ex,0.55ex) -- (1.25ex,1.05ex);
      \fi
    }},
}

\begin{document}
Tick \tikz[red]\pic{checkbox={1}}; the bigger answer:
\begin{description}
\item [{\tikz[red]\pic{checkbox={0}};}] Answer A.
{\Large\color{blue}
\item [{\tikz\pic{checkbox={0}};}] Answer B.}
\huge
\item [{\tikz\pic{checkbox={1}};}] Answer C {\bfseries (this one!!!)}.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```